# What is the difference between a Decision Tree and a Bayesian Network?

Tags: bayesian, decision-tree, bayesian-networks

If I understand it right, both use Bayes Theorem to generate an acyclic graph and calculate percentages based on functions applied at every node.

What is the difference?

Comment: Here is a [pdf](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/26803642_Comparison_of_Bayesian_network_and_decision_tree_methods_for_predicting_access_to_the_renal_transplant_waiting_list/file/79e4150b7b248e0384.pdf) to a paper: 'Comparison of Bayesian network and decision tree methods for predicting access to the renal transplant waiting list', comparing decision trees and Bayesian networks.

Answer (score 2):

One simple and fundamental difference is 
**Acyclic Graph != Tree**

For example, a->b<-c is not a tree (it has two roots), but it is an acyclic graph.

I am not well versed in decision trees, but I am well versed in Bayesian Networks.
Here are some things that you can do with Bayesian Networks that I am not sure if you can do with a decision tree. Researching how to do these things with a decision tree may reveal interesting differences.

- Compute the joint probability table between the variables
- Determine if two variables are conditionally independent
- Given some evidence, determine the distribution of the non-evidence variables given the evidence

Comment: Can the Acyclic Graph generated by a Bayesian Network be a Forest then? Because otherwise they both generate Trees since a connected Acyclic Graph is a Tree.

Comment: Yes. It is possible for two variables to be independent. In which case they are not connected.

Also a Bayesian Network does not "generate" a graph, it is a graphical representation of conditional independence relationships between the variables of a probability distribution.